# After adding the object to list value changes on changing the object

Tags: c#

```
List<ExShippingBillDetails> ExShippingBillDetailsList = new List<ExShippingBillDetails>();   
for( int i=1; i <BillsArray.Length; i++ )
{
    List<ExShippingBillDetails> ExShippingBillList = new List<ExShippingBillDetails>();
    ExShippingBillList = FinalModel( ShippingBillDetailSArray, _ExShippingBillDetails );
    ExShippingBillDetailsList.Add( ExShippingBillList[0] );
    ExShippingBillList = new List<ExShippingBillDetails>();
}
```

After adding the object to list,  when i change the property value of object(ExShippingBillList), Value in the list also changes.I dont want to change the value from list.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide us with more info? You assign a value to `ExShippingBillList`. Then you loop through it's items and last you assign a new empty list `ExShippingBillList`. It's not clear neither what you try to do nor what is your problem. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the examole just now. Please check it.Thanks for help

Comment: FinalModel()  will assign new value to object.when it assign to object data in ExShippingBillDetailsList also changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. As the object is added to the new list is pass by reference any change you make outside will also affect the original list. I have tried your example and solved your problem by creating a new object while adding to the list at this line.

```
ExShippingBillDetailsList.Add( ExShippingBillList[0] );
```

This is how I avoided value change.

```
List<ExShippingBillDetails> ExShippingBillDetailsList = new List<ExShippingBillDetails>();
List<ExShippingBillDetails> ExShippingBillList = new List<ExShippingBillDetails>();
ExShippingBillList.Add(new ExShippingBillDetails() { number = 1 });
ExShippingBillList.Add(new ExShippingBillDetails() { number = 2 });
ExShippingBillList.Add(new ExShippingBillDetails() { number = 3 });
ExShippingBillDetailsList.Add(new ExShippingBillDetails(ExShippingBillList[0]));
ExShippingBillList[0].number = 5;
//Now changing property values doesn't affect ExShippingBillDetails list

class ExShippingBillDetails
{
    public int number { get; set;}
    public ExShippingBillDetails()
    {

    }

    //you need to add this constructor to copy the values
    public ExShippingBillDetails(ExShippingBillDetails n)
    {
        number = n.number;
    }
}
```

This should solve the problem you are facing now. Good luck :)